# How to add background image only to the login page

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular-components, angular8

Hello I want add a background image just to login page component. Once the user is logged in is redirected to the home page so the background image should be disappear. I am adding the background in the html label in my css stylesheet. My code is as follow:

```
HTML{
    background:linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.5), rgba(255,255,255,.5)), url("#{$backgroundImage}/background.svg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
    font:$font;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    BODY{
        @extend HTML;
        }
        .
        .
        .
}
```

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: you should move this `css` from `HTML` tag to the container(`section` or `div`) in login.component.

Comment: @shaktimaan thank you for your quick response. You were spot on!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add the below CSS Code in your component CSS file.

```
  body { 
     background: url('/assets/Img/login.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
    }

.panel-default {
 opacity: 0.9;
 margin-top:30px;
}
.form-group.last {
 margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a component for the background; then import it for the login page.